# Calculating Total from Textbox live using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am working on a script that should essentially be updating the total costs of a form everytime the user enters a value in selected textboxes. My problem is I am not sure why it is not updating even after calls. I know I made a mistake somewhere I am just not sure where yet.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var total = document.getElementById(txtTotalCost);
      ComputeCosts();

      total.blur(function () {
        ComputeCosts();
    });
```

});

```
function ComputeCosts()
{
    var amount1 = document.getElementById(txtPAmount1);
    var amount2 = document.getElementById(txtPAmount2);
    var amount3 = document.getElementById(txtPAmount3);
    var amount4 = document.getElementById(txtPAmount4);
    var amount5 = document.getElementById(txtPAmount5);
    var totalBox = document.getElementById("txtTotalCost");          

    var totalGift = (txtPAmount1.val() +txtPAmount2.val() + txtPAmount3.val()+txtPAmount4.val()+txtPAmount5.val()).toFixed(2);
    totalBox.val(totalGift);
}
```

Here is the html side of it:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount1" CssClass="narrow" onClick="ComputeCosts();" text="0.00" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount2" CssClass="narrow" onClick="ComputeCosts();" text="0.00" />  
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount3" CssClass="narrow" onClick="ComputeCosts();" text="0.00" />  
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount4" CssClass="narrow" onClick="ComputeCosts();" text="0.00" />  
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTotalCost" CssClass="narrow" onClick="ComputeCosts();" text="0.00" />
```

Comment: You can put some `alert('test');` in there to show you where things are going bad. Are you sure that you included jquery?

Comment: @rlb.usa I am sure I added the Js at the top of the control

Comment: Why do you use `getElementById` and not jQuery selectors?

Comment: @ChruS I guess i used that way because it seem to work alot smoother when i used getelementbyID but i will attempt that way now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server controls need to be set as `ClientIDMode="Static"` or use `<%= %>` to access from client side.

You also want to convert string to float to calculate the total.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TextBoxDemo.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication2012.TextBoxDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount1" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount2" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount3" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount4" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPAmount5" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTotalCost" CssClass="narrow" 
    onClick="ComputeCosts();" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var total = $('#txtTotalCost');
        ComputeCosts();

        total.blur(function () {
            ComputeCosts();
        });
    });

    function ComputeCosts() {
        var amount1 = parseFloat($('#txtPAmount1').val());
        var amount2 = parseFloat($('#txtPAmount2').val());
        var amount3 = parseFloat($('#txtPAmount3').val());
        var amount4 = parseFloat($('#txtPAmount4').val());
        var amount5 = parseFloat($('#txtPAmount5').val());

        var totalGift = (amount1+ amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5);
        $('#txtTotalCost').val(totalGift);
    }
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied the exact same working code I tested. Please let me know if doesn't work - make sure to include javascript errors if any.

Comment: ok it worked when its on the page but i am trying it as a linked js file and it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: You cannot use linked js with `#<%= ... %>`. You need to convert those id of textboxes to `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: Hey @Win I made some changes to my code and was wondering if I could ask for your help?

Comment: Sure. Could you create a new question?

Answer (score 0):

1) Pass Client ID

```
<%=ElementName.ClientID%>
```

`document.getElementById("<%=ElementName.ClientID%>")`

2) Use onClientClick instead of onClick

3) Use `value` instead `val()`
or Use

```
var amount1 = $("#<%=txtPAmount1.ClientID%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline onclick, and use the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    ComputeCosts();

    $(".narrow").on('click', ComputeCosts).addBack().last().on('blur', ComputeCosts);

    /* 
    Above should work, if not seperate the binds
    $(".narrow").on('click', ComputeCosts);
    $("#txtTotalCost").on('blur', ComputeCosts);
    */
});

function ComputeCosts() {
    var amount1 = parseFloat($("#txtPAmount1").val());
    var amount2 = parseFloat($("#txtPAmount2").val());
    var amount3 = parseFloat($("#txtPAmount3").val());
    var amount4 = parseFloat($("#txtPAmount4").val());
    var amount5 = parseFloat($("#txtPAmount5").val());

    var totalGift = (amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5).toFixed(2);
    $("#txtTotalCost").val(totalGift);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the first line of code, and uncommenting the code block below?  You could also try wrapping the function call in the bind:

$(".narrow").on('click', function() { ComputeCosts(); });
$("#txtTotalCost").on('blur', function() { ComputeCosts(); });

Comment: I tried that. Wonder if we need to try and get this in a chat

Comment: Try accessing the input elements by their ID attribute, omitting the number part: $("input[id^='txtPAmount']").each($(this).on('click', function(){ ComputeCosts(); }));