# javascript calculation asp.net textboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a series of textboxes in a several views in a multiview control that the user enters numbers into. When the users enters numbers into textbox A3 and A4 the sum is displayed in textbox A5 which is disabled so the user cant type in it using javascript. Throughout the views this function will happen 8 times with different pairs of textboxes. Instead of me copying the javascript function 8 times is there a way i can reuse the one function and as the textbox ID's will be the only difference. Learning javascript at uni so only have basic knowledge so far.

JavaScript

```
    function A5Formula() {
        var num1 = document.getElementById("<%=A3.ClientID %>");
        var num2 = document.getElementById("<%=A4.ClientID %>");

        var t1 = 0, t2 = 0; t3 = 0

        if (num1.value != "") t1 = num1.value;
        if (num2.value != "") t2 = num2.value;
        t3 = parseInt(t1) + parseInt(t2);

        document.getElementById("<%=A5.ClientID %>").value = t3;
        document.getElementById("<%=A5hidden.ClientID %>").value = t3;
    }
```

ASP.NET

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="A3" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" onblur="A5Formula()" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="A4" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" onblur="A5Formula()" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="A5" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" Enabled="False" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks

Simplified Webpage

```
        <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
         <title></title>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function ANFormula(id1, id2, idResult) {
            var num1 = document.getElementById(id1);
            var num2 = document.getElementById(id2);

            var t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0;

            if (num1.value != "")
                t1 = num1.value;
            if (num2.value != "")
                t2 = num2.value;
            t3 = parseInt(t1) + parseInt(t2);

            document.getElementById(idResult).value = t3;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="A3">
        </asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="A3" runat="server" 
        onblur="ANFormula('<%=A3.ClientID %>', '<%=A4.ClientID %>', 
        '<%=A5.ClientID %>')"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>  
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="A4">
    </asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="A4" runat="server" 
        onblur="ANFormula('<%=A3.ClientID %>', '<%=A4.ClientID %>', 
        '<%=A5.ClientID %>')"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="A5">
                       </asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="A5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251780/calculating-total-from-textbox-live-using-javascript

Comment: You can use data- attributes, check out my answer

Comment: Were you able to review the answers Allan?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the textbox tag like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A3" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" onblur="A5Formula(this);" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

By adding "this" to the function as parameter, you are passing the object to the function( in this case textbox A3).

And in the javascript function:

```
function A5Formula(e){
if (e.id=="A3" || e.id=="A4"){
//some processing code here depending on its id and do it for other ids
}
}
```

it will check the id of the passed object to be able to control which textbox value to be changed

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell `parseInt` that you want to parse the number to a decimal number `parseInt(t1, 10)`.

And then, you could use `data-` attributes to group those controls, for instance `data-add-operation` to id operands and `data-add-operation-result` to id the result field.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A3" data-add-operation="8" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" onblur="formula(event)" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="A4" data-add-operation="8" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" onblur="formula(event)" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="A5" data-add-operation-result="8" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" Enabled="False" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And in javascript

```
function formula(e) {
    var total = 0;
    var groupId = $(e.sourceTarget).data("data-add-operation");

    $.each($("[data-add-operation=" + groupdId + "]", function(index, item) {
        total += parseInt(item.val(), 10);
    });

    $("[data-add-operation-result=" + groupdId + "]").val(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
function ANFormula(id1, id2, idResult, idHidden) {
  var num1 = document.getElementById(id1);
  var num2 = document.getElementById(id2);

  var t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0;

  if (num1.value != "") 
    t1 = num1.value;
  if (num2.value != "") 
    t2 = num2.value;
  t3 = parseInt(t1) + parseInt(t2);

  document.getElementById(idResult).value = t3;
  document.getElementById(idHidden).value = t3;
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A3" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss"  CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
  onblur="ANFormula('<%=A3.ClientID %>', '<%=A4.ClientID %>', '<%=A5.ClientID %>', '<%=A5hidden.ClientID %>')"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="A4" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"
  onblur="ANFormula('<%=A3.ClientID %>', '<%=A4.ClientID %>', '<%=A5.ClientID %>', '<%=A5hidden.ClientID %>"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="A5" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" Enabled="False" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I cant get the code to work. I have even created a simple webpage with only 3 label and 3 textboxes with the javascript and cant get it to work.